# Deserialize a JSON with nested arrays to generate a string from values

Tags: c#, json, regex

In my application I have a `List<Users>`

```
[{
"Id": "1",
"Name": "last, first",
"Skills": [{"SN":"20","SL":"12"},{"SN":"197","SL":"09"}]
},
{
"Id": "2",
"Name": "Black, Jack",
"Skills": [{"SN":"40","SL":"07"},{"SN":"199","SL":"05"}]
},
{
"Id": "3",
"Name": "Rooney, Wayne",
"Skills": [{"SN":"40","SL":"11"},{"SN":"201","SL":"07"}]
}]
```

I need to convert this data into one string in a format like this:

> "1/last, first/20-12,197-09;2/Black, Jack/40-07,199-05;3/Rooney,
>   Wayne/40-11,201-07"

I tried to serialize this object to get a JSON string:

```
public IHttpActionResult ImportUsers([FromBody]IEnumerable<Users> newUsers)
{
    string agents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newUsers);
    return Ok(agents);
}
```

and get a result:

> "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"last,
>   first\",\"Skills\":[{\"SN\":\"20\",\"SL\":\"12\"},{\"SN\":\"197\",\"SL\":\"09\"}]},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"Black,
>   Jack\",\"Skills\":[{\"SN\":\"40\",\"SL\":\"07\"},{\"SN\":\"199\",\"SL\":\"05\"}]},{\"Id\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"Rooney,
>   Wayne\",\"Skills\":[{\"SN\":\"40\",\"SL\":\"11\"},{\"SN\":\"201\",\"SL\":\"07\"}]}]"

Than I tried to deserialize this string to get values for each variables

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(agents);
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            foreach (var d in dict)
            {                
                var skills = d["Skills"];                
                string skill = string.Join(",", skills);
                string list = d["Id"] + "/" + d["Name"] + "/" + skill;
                results.Add(list);
            }
            string result = string.Join(";", results);
```

and get this string:

> "1/last, first/{\r\n \"SN\": \"20\",\r\n \"SL\": \"12\"\r\n},{\r\n
>   \"SN\": \"197\",\r\n \"SL\": \"09\"\r\n};2/Black, Jack/{\r\n \"SN\":
>   \"40\",\r\n \"SL\": \"07\"\r\n},{\r\n \"SN\": \"199\",\r\n \"SL\":
>   \"05\"\r\n};3/Rooney, Wayne/{\r\n \"SN\": \"40\",\r\n \"SL\":
>   \"11\"\r\n},{\r\n \"SN\": \"201\",\r\n \"SL\": \"07\"\r\n}"

So it's more like what I need, but I still have a problem with values in Skills list. How can I get values from it like it was with Id and Name columns? Maybe I need to deserialize this part one more time or use some regular expressions to achieve the string that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result is not a valid json. Then the better way is to format result string via c# without 3rd party libraries.

Laconic way is to use string functiions:

```
public IHttpActionResult ImportUsers([FromBody] IEnumerable<User> newUsers)
{
    var agents = string.Join(";", newUsers.Select(GetFormattedUserString));
    return Ok(agents);
}

private string GetFormattedUserString(User user)
{
    return string.Concat(user.Id, "/", user.Name, "/", string.Join(",", user.Skills.Select(skill => string.Concat(skill.SN, "-", skill.SL))));
}
```

Efficient and less understandable (for my opinion) way is to use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public IHttpActionResult ImportUsers([FromBody] IEnumerable<User> newUsers)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var user in newUsers)
    {
        sb.Append(user.Id);
        sb.Append("/");

        sb.Append(user.Name);
        sb.Append("/");

        for (int i = 0; i < user.Skills.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(user.Skills[i].SN);
            sb.Append("-");
            sb.Append(user.Skills[i].SL);
            if (i != user.Skills.Length)
                sb.Append(",");
        }

        sb.Append(";");
    }

    var result = sb.ToString();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Simply amazing! Both of them are work great. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your code to make it work. In order to get the skills in the way you want, you can nest another `foreach` loop that will create a list of skills in the requested format:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(agents);
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (var d in dict)
{
    List<string> skills = new List<string>();

    foreach (var s in d["Skills"])
    {
        skills.Add(s["SN"].ToString() + "-" + s["SL"].ToString());
    }

    string skill = string.Join(",", skills);
    string list = d["Id"] + "/" + d["Name"] + "/" + skill;
    results.Add(list);
}
string result = string.Join(";", results);
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. It is really helpful for me!